# How do I PIVOT in SQL without Columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my query

```
  SELECT 
  Count(case when IPAddress0 like '10.172.%' then 1 else null end) as HW
 ,Count(case when DNSHostName0 like '50%' then 1 else null end) as HN
  From v_Network_DATA_Serialized
```

(about 50 more "Count's", so instead of 50 colums, id like them to show up as a row each.

I have tried a few PIVOT's but usually error's out on Column [HW] is not contained within the PIVOT.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try UNPIVOT

```
SELECT CountType, MyCounts
FROM
  (SELECT 
    Count(case when IPAddress0 like '10.172.%' then 1 else null end) as HW
    ,Count(case when DNSHostName0 like '50%' then 1 else null end) as HN
  FROM v_Network_DATA_Serialized) p
UNPIVOT
  (MyCounts FOR CountType IN
    (HW, HN)
) as up;
```

Comment: Amazing, I totally missed adding the SELECT CountType, MyCounts than pivoting on them (or un pivoting)

Answer (score 0):

I would add a column to your table v_Network_DATA_Serialized which indicates the name of the relevant aggregate. Let's say, as an example, "agg_alias".

Then, update your existing records so that they include the correct alias. As two examples, given your example data:

```
update v_Network_DATA_Serialized set agg_alias = 'HW' where IPAddress0 like '10.172.%';
update v_Network_DATA_Serialized set agg_alias = 'HN' where DNSHostName0 like '50%';
```

This will record the correct alias for the existing records just for those 2 counts. To do this on an ongoing basis, you can have the data be entered each time, or automatically have it populated through a trigger. (depends on how the table is being populated). You could add a trigger to always populate the column with the correct alias given the other values, for all 50 or so counts you'll be doing.

Afterwards, doing this query would be as simple as:

```
select      agg_alias
            , count(*)
from        v_Network_DATA_Serialized
group by    agg_alias
```

As an alternative approach, you could calculate each count in one query across 50 unions, ex.

```
select count(*) as counter, 'HW' as agg_alias
  from v_Network_DATA_Serialize
 where IPAddress0 like '10.172.%'
union all
select count(*) as counter, 'HN' as agg_alias
  from v_Network_DATA_Serialized
 where DNSHostName0 like '50%'
```

(for the 2 example counts you gave). But I would do it the first way.